# I cannot connect Postgres DB with Strapi on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, strapi

I try to set up Strapi + PostgresDB on Heroku.

I follow this manual step by step https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/heroku.html

When I deploy to Heroku I get: Application error

`heroku logs --tail` shows

```
npm ERR! my-host-cms@0.1.0 start: `strapi start`
2020-06-09T14:54:44.272624+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-06-09T14:54:44.272950+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-06-09T14:54:44.273144+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the my-host-cms@0.1.0 start script.
2020-06-09T14:54:44.273335+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-06-09T14:54:44.289977+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-09T14:54:44.290269+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-06-09T14:54:44.290445+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-09T14_54_44_278Z-debug.log
2020-06-09T14:54:44.353188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-09T14:54:44.386798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-09T14:54:44.388614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-09T14:55:01.903657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-09T14:55:05.469266+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-09T14:55:05.469295+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-host-cms@0.1.0 start /app
2020-06-09T14:55:05.469296+00:00 app[web.1]: > strapi start
2020-06-09T14:55:05.469296+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-09T14:55:08.015032+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-09T14:55:08.013Z] error The client `sqlite3` is not installed.
2020-06-09T14:55:08.015961+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-09T14:55:08.015Z] error You can install it with `$ npm install sqlite3 --save`.
```

and

```
2020-06-09T14:55:09.623864+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-host.herokuapp.com request_id=eea79361-593f-413e-89e2-d99d0153ddf3 fwd="37.57.145.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

```
2020-06-09T15:01:07.901262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=my-host.herokuapp.com request_id=ce0353b0-5e45-422d-af43-f96614c8151d fwd="37.57.145.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I see it asks about `sqlite3` but I have it package.json

The project was inited with `--quickstart` but I have made `./config/environments/production/database.json`

Answer (score 0):

If you installed strapi with the --quickstart flag then by default it would provision a SQLite db for you.

- since you loading a db config for postpres, make sure you installed pg.
- you can npm/yarn remove sqlite3 from your package.json if you not using it locally, ie.you have postgres installed and the service is running.
- delete your cache folder and then `npm run build`
- now push to heroku and open.

fyi. it is recommended that you have database.js over database.json
eg.

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'postgres',
        host: env('DATABASE_HOST'),
        port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT'),
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL'),
      },
      options: {}
    },
  },
});
```

In Heroku make sure that the postgres addon is provisioned.
check your config vars in heroku for the app is correct.
also make sure ./config/database.js or ./config/database.json has also been corrected to use the correct database.